# What is the proper way to inject a service in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular8

I am trying to inject a service to my main "App" component. But it gives an error(Screenshot attached Below)

```
constructor(private newsApi: NewsApiService) {}
```

When importing service with the above code I get this error
[image]

I googled and found the solution. Which is adding

> @Inject

```
constructor(@Inject(NewsApiService) newsApi: NewsApiService) {}
```

But in the documentation of Angular.io, it shows the first way that I used. I want to know if I am missing something here?

My NewsApiService has HttpClient and it sends HTTP request. Functions written in this service are all Async as they need to send a request and get data.

**NewsApiService.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsApiService {
  apiKey = '--My_API_Key_Goes_here--';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  initSources() {
    return this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?language=en&apiKey=' + this.apiKey);
  }

  initArticles() {
    return this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=' + this.apiKey);
  }

  getArticlesByID(source: string) {
    return this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=' + source + '&apiKey=' + this.apiKey);
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**
Added the service in provider to access everywhere

> providers: [NewsApiService],

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatToolbarModule
} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NewsApiService} from './news-api.service';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
  ],
  providers: [NewsApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NewsApiService} from './news-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent{
  mArticles: Array<any>;
  mSources: Array<any>;

  constructor(@Inject(NewsApiService) newsApi: NewsApiService) {}
}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `app.module.ts`

Comment: If you use `providedIn: 'root'`, you do not need to add this service to the `providers` array. Are you importing `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`? If you are, your code should be working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9xt1b

Comment: I edited and added my app.module.ts file too

Comment: Yes, I am importing HttpClientModule in app.module.ts

Comment: Have you tried killing the `ng serve` process and restarting it? I don't see any reason why your code should not work without `@Inject`

Comment: Not sure if it is a copy/paste oversight but there is no `ngOnInit` method in `AppComponent` even though it implements `OnInit`.

Comment: LOL. I just tried and it worked now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy the ngOnInIt method. It was there

Comment: No worries, it does not matter now anyways as you found the answer. This is something I have to do every once in a while as well when adding new code files.

Comment: I am just new to Frontend Development. I know I have to face a lot of such issues. 
And thanks

Comment: is there any method to inject without constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have to restart `ng serve` for it to pick up changes in new files. I experience this occasionally with injector dependencies where I add a new code file that serves as a dependency in another component/service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the injection explicitly vs Injectable, please have a look at the already answered post:

[What is the difference between @Inject and @Injectable in Angular 2 typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315317/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-injectable-in-angular-2-typescript)

Answer (score -1):

Use @Injectable() Decorator which enables a class to be injected to a particular class or component.

Basically the following three steps makes service consumption

1.) Decorate the service with @Injectable() like
@Injectable()
export class SampleService{
constructor(){
}
}

2.) Add the service reference in the providers array of @NgModule Decorator of module file.

3.)// Consume the service
constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {}

As far as I see your screenshot, it is not a staticInjector error which is thrown in case of injection issue.